# Initializer list as a variadic template argument

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

I have a couple of classes A, B, and F, all having different constructor signatures, like these:

```
class A {
public:
     A() {}
};

class B {
    double x_, y_;
public:
    B(double x, double y) : x_(x), y_(y) {}
};

class F {
    vector<unsigned> factors_;
public:
    F(std::initializer_list<unsigned> factors) : factors_(factors) {}
};
```

The objects of these classes need to be registered somewhere, so the construction should go through a factory, like this:

```
template<class R, typename... Args>
inline R & factory(Args &&... args)
{
    R * rp = new R(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    /* do fancy stuff with rp... */
    return *rp;
}
```

This works fine for classes A and B, but not for F, because typename... wants to take one or more types:

```
A & a = factory<A>();   // okay     
B & b = factory<B>(0.707107, 0.707107);  // okay
F & f = factory<F>({2, 3, 5, 7, 11});  // error: no matching function for call to ‘F::F()’ in factory
```

Question: Is there any way to make it work with the general `factory<R>(args...)` syntax?

I tried a full specialization of the factory function for `<F, std::initializer_list>`, but either messed up the syntax or, when it compiled, wasn't picked up as factory by the compiler.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be your preferred syntax, but you can force the factory method to pass an initializer list:

```
F & f = factory<F>(std::initializer_list<unsigned>{2u, 3u, 5u, 7u, 11u});
```

I explicitly made the literals unsigned here - although they could be coerced by the `std::initializer_list<unsigned>`, that isn't the case with the following version.

I was able to get it working with an overload of `factory()`:

```
template<class R>
inline R& do_fancy_stuff_with(R *r)
{
    /* do fancy stuff here... */
    return *r;
}

template<class R, typename... Args>
inline R & factory(Args &&... args)
{
    R * rp = new R(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return do_fancy_stuff_with(rp);
}

template<class R, typename T>
inline R & factory(std::initializer_list<T> args)
{
    R * rp = new R(std::move(args));
    return do_fancy_stuff_with(rp);
}

A & a = factory<A>();
B & b = factory<B>(0.707107, 0.707107);
F & f = factory<F>({2u, 3u, 5u, 7u, 11u});
```

I'm surprised that variadic templates don't play more nicely with initializer lists.

Comment: The OP used integers during his initialization. This would break std::initializer_list<T> args, as ...list<int> is not convertable to ...list<unsigned>.

Comment: @Werner Yes, that's why I explicitly used unsigned ints.

Comment: Yes, but he didn't, and you've not clarified this in your answer. Apart from that I agree with your answer (although I think using vector is a better option) - I also started out similarly to you.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question: I can't see a simple way of reusing your factory method which takes an initializer_list.

I would personally add a constructor in class F taking a `std::vector`

```
F(const std::vector<unsigned>& factors) : factors_(factors) {}
```

and rewrite a factory method :

```
template<class R>
inline R & factory(const std::vector<unsigned>& factors)
{
    R *rp = new R(factors);
    /* do fancy stuff with rp... */
    return *rp;
}
```

Now it compiles fine.

**[Live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed23ecaa7f62d20c)**

If you want to avoid code duplication you should consider writing your `/* do fancy stuff with rp... */` in another function.

**Edit**

I don't know what you want to do, but why don't you simply use here :

```
F f2{2, 3, 5, 7, 11};
```

You don't need a factory if you just want to populate your class F vector with some values.

Comment: In more complete code, one can imagine that the factory is there to register the objects somewhere.